# Adding sub-regex inside regex to match text after first pipe

Tags: regex

#### Goal

I'm trying to match two things inside brackets, first the string after dollar, and next optionally string after text.

| Text | Match 1 | Match 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `lorem {{ $name }} ipsus` | `name` | - |
| `lorem {{ $name | pipe1 | pipe2 }} ipsus` | `name` | `pipe1 | pipe2` |
| `lorem {{ $name | singlePipe }} ipsus` | `name` | `singlePipe` |
| `lorem {{ $ whitespaceBeforeDollar | singlePipe }} ipsus` | - | - |
| `lorem {{ noDollar | pipe1 | pipe2 }} ipsus` | - | - |
| `lorem {{ $name textWithoutPipe }} ipsus` | - | - |
| `lorem {{$whiteSpace | tolerated}} ipsus` | `whitespace` | `tolerated` |
| `lorem {{$whiteSpace|tolerated}} ipsus` | `whitespace` | `tolerated` |

#### What I've tried

First part (name after dollar) I can match using: `/{{\s*\$\s*([^}| ]+)\s*}}/g` (see: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wTjPZ8/1))

However I fail at matching the second part. For second part I tried using adding the bold part to first one, but it does not work: `/{{\s*\$\s*([^}| ]+)`**`(?:\|\s*((?:(?!{{).)*?)\s*)?`**`\s*}}/g`

#### Question

How can get my regex working or write one that matches both?

I tried to do it in a way so I can remove the part matching 2 and match 1 would continue matching without pipes. And if both exists, it matches both. So something like `{{regex-matching-one (<<regex-matching-two>>)}}` so I can just remove the second regex inside first one it still works.

I contribute to a non-profit open-source project and will use the regex for it.

Comment: Your examples are detailed. Thank you. I'm a bit confused as to why `lorem {{ $name }} ipsus` should match $name and `lorem {{ $name textWithoutPipe }} ipsus` should not. I guess because of the white space?

Comment: H Aaron, thank you for your comment. Yes the reason is the lack of the pipe | in between them. I try to do some kind of templating so one could have a variable and pipe to different functions, but one needs to write right syntax with pipe (`|`) otherwise it mean something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex to get all expected matches

```sh
{{\s*\$([^|\s]+)\s*(?:\|\s*(.+?)\s*)?}}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wTjPZ8/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `{{`: Match opening `{{`
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `\$`: Match a `$`
- `([^|\s]+)`: First capture group to match 1+ of any characters that are nor`|` and whitespace
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `(?:`: Start a non-capturing group

  - `\|`: Match a `|`
  - `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
  - `(.+?)`: Second capture group to match 1+ of any character
  - `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `)?`: End non-capturing group. `?` makes this an optional match
- `}}`: Match closing `}}`

Comment: Seems to work fine without the `?:` non-capturing group.

Comment: It will work without non-capture group but then 2nd group will become 3rd group